# How can I get output node names from a keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras

As the title says, I need to get output node names from my keras xception model. Specifically, I want to use this information to freeze it for use with opencv.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Can you please word this more clearly? Would you like to get the weights of your model after an epoch?

Comment: I am trying to get output_node_names for use by freeze_graph.freeze_graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
model = keras.models.load_model( 'yourModel.h5' )
output = model.output
```

output:

> KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.float32,
> name=None), name='Bottleneck_BatchNorm/batchnorm/add_1:0',
> description="created by layer 'Bottleneck_BatchNorm'")

Comment: I tried this and I get this error: AssertionError: dense/BiasAdd:0 is not in graph (dense/BiasAdd:0 being the output).
Full message: KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='dense/BiasAdd:0', description="created by layer 'dense'")

Comment: Also as a side note, I get two .pb files from model.save(model_directory). Im guessing it isn't possible to directly use those.